# How do I set and increment a ticket number before save in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, simple-form

I'm making tickets for a small (<150 person) event and would like to auto increment ticket numbers and save those numbers to the database. Do I use a "hidden_field"? My database is set up with ticket.number as an array, because a person may buy several tickets. So what's the proper syntax? Thanks!

Comment: Needs more information. Can you provide the related model code and db relations you are using?

Comment: Why don't you have a `Ticket` model and use its `id` as the ticket number? And why is `ticket.number` an array?

Answer (score 0):

Is your database PostgreSQL?  That supports storing arrays natively, so you can do

```
"select max(select max(x) from unnest(ticket_array) x) from people"
```

I haven't tested it so I'm not positive about the phrasing but it's something like that.

However your database is small enough that you can do it in Rails which should work for any type of database if you're storing the array as a serialised string.

```
last_number = Person.all.map{|person| person.ticket_array.max }.max
```

You'd use this in a `before save`, and I assume you have an integer column `number_of_tickets`, so you could do...

```
class Person

  serialize :ticket_array

  before_save :determine_ticket_numbers

  def determine_ticket_numbers
    return if persisted?
    last_number = self.class.all.map{|person| person.ticket_array.max }.max
    last_number ||= 0
    number_of_tickets.times { self.ticket_array << (last_number += 1) }
  end
end
```